# The longest string

Tags: c, arrays, string, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm going through K&R C programming language book and try to solve all the exercises.

There is a sample program that finds the longest string in the input. It basically reads strings from input one by one and store the longest in the array with pre-defined length. In other words it assumes the upper bound on the length of the longest string.

After this program there is an exercise that asks to change the program such that it does not assume the bound on the length. I have no idea how to achieve this without using dynamic memory allocation (which is discussed in the following chapters of the book).

If I'm correct, arrays in C are defined during the compilation so their length is static unless we allocate memory dynamically.

Comment: Have a glance at [Variable-length_array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)

Comment: If the length of the input string is unknown, then you need dynamic memory allocation is you want to allocate the minimum amount of memory. If you have a top bound size, then just define an array of that size.

Comment: Does it find the string or find the length? I.e. do you need to report the string's content at the end or just the length, and perhaps the line number? Perhaps with those 2 bits of info you could read through the file again to print the string.

Comment: @kiranBiradar It's not obvious  how to use VLAs to solve the described problem, since you can't re-allocate them. You'd have to rewind the input and try again with a larger array, which is not possible in general.

Comment: @unwind I got your point, maybe it is possible if we declare the array local to the scope(loop) and use `strlen`?

Comment: If there is no requirement to store the string, then simply use `fgetc` to get char-by-char and count, and remember the largest count.

Comment: Create a tempfile and store the line in there. Open a pipe and use pipe's internal buffer as your string buffer.

Comment: Okay, okay, I've just started so files and pipes are overkill   :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are referring to exercise 1.16 on page 30.
The complete statement is

> **Exercise 1-16.** Revise the main routine of the longest-line program so it will
>   correctly print the length of arbitrarily long input lines, and as much as possible
>   of the text.

It is impossible to return the whole string if its length is arbitrary, because you would have to store it, and that would require dynamic memory allocation. However, you can slightly modify the main routine so it will correctly compute the length of the string, and output "as much as possible" of the text, i.e. up to a fixed length.

Here is one possible answer:

```
#define MAXLINE 1000 /* maximum input line size */

main() {
    int buf_len; /* current buffer length (<= MAXLINE) */
    int len = 0; /* current full line length */
    int max = 0; /* maximum length seen so far */
    char buffer[MAXLINE];  /* current input line */
    char line[MAXLINE];    /* prefix of longest-line candidate */
    char longest[MAXLINE]; /* longest line saved here */

    while ((buf_len = getline(buffer, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        if (len == 0) /* this is the first chunk of the string */
            copy(line, buffer);
        len += buf_len;
        if (buf_len < MAXLINE || buffer[MAXLINE-2] == '\n') {
            /* the string was terminated */
            if (len > max) {
                max = len;
                copy(longest, line);
            }
            /* this line was fully processed */
            /* now reset len to 0 and process the next string */
            len = 0;
        }
    }
    if (max > 0)
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not encourage giving complete answers for excercises where someone is clearly learning. Just give hints and let them find (learn!) the solution themselves.

Comment: Okay, I got the problem -- I'm using Russian translation of the book. And it seems like this exercise was incorrectly translated (at least in my edition), I will definitely switch to the original book. Thanks for pointing this out, the correct formulation sounds manageable.

Comment: I think the issue here was the problem statement, not the solving, and the misinterpretation of "as much as possible". Since the comments were starting to discuss VLAs, pipes and stack-vs-heap allocation, which are all both off the point and beyond the scope of this exercise, I chose to give a simple answer that does not use nested loops, nor fails on lines of exactly MAXLINE characters, which might not be trivial at first sight and could easily be missed as no test cases are provided. Understanding answers is also learning, and OP seemed able to solve it on his own. I take you point though